# what are the properties of an asynchronous database driver?

Tags: asynchronous, database-connection, theory

Today I was discussing with some python friends some of the challenges in managing connection pools in async networking frameworks like Twisted and Tornado.

I know there are community developed async alternatives for these kinds of situations, but that led me to wonder...

**What is the complete list of properties for a good asynchronous database library?**

I'm aware of the core principle behind making a database connection/cursor work correctly in an async environment - don't block waiting for a query to return (or for that matter, more generally, don't block at all of course).  Are there other caveats?  What are the main guidelines?  If one was to set to the task of making an async driver alternative to a major db solution, what is the full criteria such a solution would have to satisfy?  What type of unit and functional testing should be applied to code that directly utilizes a DB query protocol to keep it consistently asynchronous?

Comment: Here is someone's blog post "[What do you want from a database driver?](http://adamfowlerml.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/what-do-you-want-from-a-database-driver/)" I wonder whether you'll find it relevant.